# Geth "invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address" error

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I run following request to Geth:

```
POST http://localhost:8545

{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"id":1,
"method": "eth_sign",
  "params": [
    {
      "from": "0xDc89096c0E279933a7C99e13f1474A0a84320207",
      "gas": "0x55555",
      "maxFeePerGas": "0x1234",
      "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x1234",
      "input": "",
      "nonce": "0x0",
      "to": "0xCdde93eEDC6c911D33E7fe41DC05208E0630a4c0",
      "value": "0x1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

but getting following error:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32602,
        "message": "invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address"
    }
}
```

Geth Version: Geth/v1.10.26-stable-e5eb32ac/windows-amd64/go1.18.5

What can be reason?

Answer (score 1):

[eth_sign](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sign) is meant for signing arbitrary messages - not transactions - and takes 2 params:

1. Address of the signer. It assumes that the signer has an unlocked account on the node (i.e. the node knows the private key that derives into this address).
2. The message to sign

---

Based on the params that you're passing, it seems that you want to sign a transaction instead. For that, there's the [eth_signTransaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_signtransaction) method.

Again, it succeeds only if the node knows the private key to the `from` address, and the account holding the private key is unlocked on the node.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I confused of end-points and working well now.